# Reimann-Stieltjes Integral and Expectation for Discrete Random Variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, riemann-integration

This is an problem from real analysis, when learning Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

A discrete random variable is an $X$ such that $X(\Omega)$ is countable (possibly finite), say $X(\Omega) = \left\{x_i, i\in \Bbb N\right\}$. Suppose that these values $x_i$ all lie in $[a,b]$, and suppose that the probability that $X$ takes the value $x_i$ is $p_i \in [0, 1]$, with  sum of all $p_i = 1$. The expectation of $X$ is defined to be $$E[X] = \sum_{i\in \Bbb N} x_i  p_i$$ Find $F : [a,b] \to [0,1]$, monotone increasing with $F(a) = 0$ and $F(b) = 1$, such that $$E[X] =  \int_a^b x \,dF(x)$$

I though I can can construct $F$ as $$\sum_{i\in\Bbb N} p_i  I(x-x_i)$$ where $I$ is the left-continuous unit step function, and by the theorems in Rudin, $E[X]$ indeed equals to that integral. Also, $F(a) = 0$ is satisfied. But the only problem is that if $\{x_i, i \in \Bbb N\}$ contains $b$, then $F(b)$ will not equals $1$ (because the left-continuous unit step function $I(x)$ takes $0$ when $x = 0$). So I am struggling how to handle this case.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ next time for a better reading… added it myself. Please double check my changes.

To answer your question: Just change your assumptions to: "Suppose that these values $x_i$ all lie in $(a,b)$ and consider $[a,b]$. Then your case cannot happen.

Comment: @Gono but the assumption is given by the question and I cannot change that......

Comment: What you are actually looking for is the distribution function of $X$ and such a distribution function has to be right-continuous. Hence Just change the left-continuous unit step function by the right-continuous one but then same same problem will occur with $a$ instead of $b$ but for a distribution function this is fine. 
If you really want to have a function that fits your assumptions (although it's not a distribution function anymore) use the left-continuous unit step function for $$x_i \le \frac{b-a}{2}$$ and the right-continuous one else. Then you get exactly the behavior you want.